# dockerd does not start debian

Tags: debian, docker, daemon, systemctl

Linux OS: debian11
Everything worked, but I think today after sudo apt upgrade I installed new version of docker.
Then docker daemon does not start:

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I checked the logs:

Here are the start today

```
$ sudo journalctl -xu docker.service    
May 27 09:07:11 debian systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit docker.service has finished successfully.
░░
```

Then I ran apt update && apt upgrade and docker is not running anymore there is a problem with graph directive not matching configuration..:(

```
$ sudo journalctl -xu docker.service
May 27 09:20:43 debian dockerd[12661]: unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives don't match any configuration option: graph
May 27 09:20:43 debian systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

This is how my daemon.json looks like

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "graph": "/data/docker/docker-data/"
}
```

Docker version

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
```

I tryed to remove docker and reinstall but no luck.

**I accept the answer and put the solution here**

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "data-root" : "/data/docker/docker-data/"
}
```

Comment: Please don't add solutions to the question. You can, however, answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`graph` is [not supported any more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#-g-and---graph-flags-on-dockerd).

> The -g or --graph flag for the dockerd or docker daemon command was used to indicate the directory in which to store persistent data and resource configuration and has been replaced with the more descriptive --data-root flag. These flags were deprecated and hidden in v17.05, and removed in v23.0.

You're running v24.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS here, this  worked perfectly